# AngularJS prevent ngModel sync

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive called `po-datepicker`, it displays a datepicker on the screen, but allows the user to type a date manually:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" po-datepicker required />
```

and this is the directive:

```
myApp.directive('poDatepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: ['?^ngModel'],
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var ngModel = ctrl[0];
            var picker = elem.datepicker();

            picker.on('changeDate', function(e) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(e.date);
                ...
            });

            elem.parent().find('button').on('click', function() {
                picker.datepicker('show');
            });

            var changeFn = function(e) {
                // Here I have some logic that calls $setViewValue();
            };

            picker.on('hide', changeFn);
            elem.on('keyup blur', changeFn);
        }
    };
});
```

this works as expected, but when I try to type a value in the input, it updates the ngModel, changing the variable in the scope, how can I prevent ngModel from being changed in the input?

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZxvglPYwX95ufXN4IbdN?p=preview), try manually writing a value and you'll understand what I'm talking.

Comment: Why don't you associate the text input with a different model object. Then at the appropriate time, you can commit the value to the real model object.

Comment: If I do that, the validations such as `required` will not work, since it needs `ngModel` to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after some research, I found a solution for this problem.

What I found on forums and questions is that I needed to unbind the element's events, like this:

```
elem.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
```

But that solution didn't work as expected.

The problem is that I'm currently using Angular 1.2.x, I found out that you need also to set some priority to the directive, such as:

```
return {
    require: ['?^ngModel'],
    priority: 1,
    ...
}
```

The `priority: 1` is needed in this case, because of the priority of some internal Angular.js directives.

[Here is an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LFChan0m8wBHYr7B2fIx?p=preview) with the right priority set up.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'disabled' to the input [**http://plnkr.co/edit/xFeAmSCtKdNSQR1zbAsd?p=preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xFeAmSCtKdNSQR1zbAsd?p=preview)

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="test" po-datepicker required feedback disabled/>
```

Comment: the user needs the option to set the value manually too, that's the problem

Comment: what about solution like that  http://plnkr.co/edit/Ax2Rd7ybaISUw0yMcfIj?p=preview